# Google Colab started freezing when working with moviepy

Tags: google-colaboratory, progress-bar, moviepy

It used to be fine, but now in all notepads, all accounts, browsers and on all computers I'm seeing the same problem. Sometimes something starts glitching, and then when running a function from moviepy write_videofile(), the loading animation doesn't remove the previous progress bars, and there are many of them printed one after another. But there were no particular problems with this before. But recently when this happens (video is exported to the file system in this way), the tab with this Google Colab notepad hangs intentionally. Then the result appears, however it really bothers me as I can't do anything at that moment and I have no way to see the progress. In addition, the computer's CPU is about 30% utilized by this tab while doing this.

I've tried running similar code on different computers, from different accounts, in different browsers and notepads. But this problem appeared everywhere.

To remove the progress bar, I should call a function with the argument logger = None, am I right?